# How to query users with Permission set License?

Tags: userlicense

I have 10 Event Monitoring Analytics Apps licenses in my org but not sure who is using those licenses.
How can I query which users are using these licenses?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can query those users from the Developer Console's Query Editor tab:

```
SELECT AssigneeId FROM PermissionSetLicenseAssign WHERE PermissionSetLicenseId = '...'
```

The PermissionSetLicense itself can be queried to find out the ID you need:

```
SELECT Id, MasterLabel FROM PermissionSetLicense
```